# NoneType and Int Operands

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function in my code that taake in two parameters

```
def cost_per_student(nparrloans,nparrrecipients): 
  nparrloanperstudent = (nparrloans)*1000000000/(nparrrecipients)*1000000
  return nparrloanperstudent
```

Whenever I run my code it goes to this function saying that i have an unsupported operand for the nonetype and int. Is there any way to make it possible, Ive tried making the nonetypes into int but to no avail

Here is the rest of my code

```
from csv import * 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#Step 5 
def read_data(filename): 
  try: 
    array = np.genfromtxt("filename", delimiter=',', usecols=(1,2,3,4,5,6)) 
  except IOError: 
    print("File not found") 

#Step 6 
def cost_per_student(nparrloans,nparrrecipients): 
  nparrloanperstudent = (nparrloans) *1000000000/(nparrrecipients)*1000000
  return nparrloanperstudent 

#Step 7 
def read_labels(filename): 
  labels= [] 
  try: 
    labelFile = open(filename, "r") 
    for line in labelFile: 
      line.strip() 
      line.title() 
      lables.append(line) 
    labelFile.close() 
  except IOError: 
    print("Label file not found") 
  return labels 

#Step 8 
def display_amounts_whole(npdata, labels, title): 
  labels = labels 
  sizes = npdata 
  plt.title(title) 
  plt.show() 

#Step 9 
def write_averages_to_file(filename,labels,averages): 
  if len(labels) == len(averages): 
    try: 
      file = open(filename, ' w' , newline='') 
      csvfile  = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ',') 
      for i in range(len(labels)): 
        csvfile.writerow(labels, averages) 
      csvfile.close() 
    except IOError: 
      print("Output file not valid") 
  else: 
    print("Labels do not match average") 

#Step 10 
def main(): 
  loanamts = read_data("Loan_amounts_by_type_data.csv") 
  population = read_data("Loan_amounts_by_type_number.csv") 
  dataLabels = read_labels("loan_types.txt") 
  calculation = cost_per_student(loanamts, population) 
  display_amounts_whole(population, dataLabels, "Loan Amounts by Type\n4th 
    Quarter 2017")  

#Step 11 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  main()
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Later in the code I have calculation = cost_per_student(loanamts, population)

Comment: So, what are `loanamts` and `population` equal to?

Comment: @deadalias Then one of the arguments that you're giving to the function is None. You'll need to debug to find out why, or provide more context so we can help you.

Comment: And how are `loanamts` and `population` defined?  The error indicates one of them is `None`, and you can't do math with `None`.

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `read_data`, so `population` and `loanamts` will be `None`.

Comment: Thats the part that confuses me.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your question to follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Values (nparrloans,nparrrecipients) is none when you call the function .

if you are sure that your code is right i think it need some organizing , so when you call

the function you have both argument (nparrloans,nparrrecipients) defined .